# Is there any way to know how much a companion likes me?

Tags: fallout-4

I know that you can always ask your companions how your relationship is going but when I'm trying to max everyone's relationships, it'd be nice to know *exactly* how much my companions like me. Is there an actual value for this? Can I tell how close to the next relationship rank I am?

Comment: While the answer is correct, you should note that there are a few mods you can download which make it possible to check the progress ingame without being forced into the console the entire itme.

Comment: @YUNOWORK for consoles or just PC? I'm on PS4.

Comment: I thought PS4 mods for Fallout 4 were on hold due to controversy or something?

Comment: @TimmyJim There are mods for Fallout 4 on PS4, but I think there's an issue with external assets that makes it so that many of the mods on PC and XBox can't be ported over. I don't see any mods that show companion affinity for PS4 on the Bethesda Mods site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity)

> The affinity value is a hidden statistic, meaning it is not possible to check the progress without console commands.

If you're not on PC, it appears you're out of luck as there is no way to know. If you're on PC, you can check through console commands.

Try this:

- Open up console
- Click on the companion you wish to check
- Type `GetAV CA_Affinity`

Here is a scale for telling how much affinity is earned for each action:

- Companion Liked that +15
- Companion Loved that +35
- Companion Disliked that -15
- Companion Hated that -35

If you're looking to trigger new quests from companions, the Wiki also says:

> For most companions, new dialogue will be triggered when the affinity value reaches 250, 500, 750 and 1000.

Some extra information about affinity:

> Typically, all companions begin at an affinity value of 0. If the affinity value reaches 500, they will "admire" the Sole Survivor and often reveal new dialogue. Raising their affinity to 1000+ (max is 1100) will result in them "idolizing" the Sole Survivor, at which point the Sole Survivor are granted their companion perk.

Comment: The `GetAV CA_Affinity` doesn't seem to be working anymore. I checked in v 1.10.163 and it always shows affinity 0.00